# "Не сводимое". Почему раздельное написание "не"?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

> ...явление, не сводимое к простым трактовкам.

Почему автор учебника "Обществознание" *не* пишет раздельно? Прилагательное на *-мый* пишется слитно, раздельно, если зависимое слово стоит в творит. падеже.
Также в предложении:

> ...опыт, не свободный от заблуждений.

Несвободный, т.е зависимый. Зависимые слова на правописание НЕ с прилагательными не влияют. Тогда почему раздельно?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что чувствуется отрицание. Впрочем, в первом случае я бы сказал, что возможно и слитное написание.

> > Зависимые слова на правописание НЕ с прилагательными не влияют

Еще как влияют. Но не всегда.

Answer (score 1):

В примерах, которые Вы привели (если ориентироваться только по данному контексту),нужно слитное написание. Однако при более широком контексте раздельное написание, возможно, будет оправдано.

Answer (score 1):

Раздельное написание НЕ связано, скорее всего, с  ОБОСОБЛЕНИЕМ прилагательных, которые НЕ УПОТРЕБЛЯЮТСЯ без зависимых слов (в этом случае неясна их семантика):

Явление, не сводимое к простым трактовкам.  Опыт, не свободный от заблуждений.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Следует обратить внимание на  прилагательные, которые имеют при себе пояснительные слова, без которых они НЕ УПОТРЕБЛЯЮТСЯ: склонный к простуде ребенок, готовый к выходу актер, свойственный ему стиль.

Орфография таких выражений трактуется не всегда однозначно:

А) шахматист играл в несвойственном ему стиле – слитное написание НЕ в утвердительной конструкции;

Б) Это черты, не свойственные нашей молодежи  –  раздельное написание НЕ  при ОБОСОБЛЕНИИ (прилагательное по значению близко к причастию).

ПРИМЕРЫ

1) Необособленные обороты

Григорий и в себе радостно ощущал эту несвойственную ему за последние годы податливость на смех. Почему я пошел на такой несвойственный мне шаг?

2) Обособленные обороты

Не склонный к полуправдам, могу сказать: нет скорби о потерянном, нет страха перед смертью во Вселенной.В них был живой интерес, ему самому не свойственный.

См Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77  пункт 8

Answer (score 0):

явление, несводимое к простым трактовкам 
несводимое - прилагательное, так как это отглагольное образование от глагола сводить - переходного, несовершенного вида. От таких глаголов образуется причастие на -мый только при наличии пояснительного слова в творительном падеже (творительного действующего лица или творительного орудия). Следовательно, в данном случае это прилагательное и по общим правилам написания прилагательных с *не* надо писать вместе.